# Can I manipulate event listener using hooks in react app?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-state

is it possible to enable/disable event listener based on useState hook ?

I created a Hook:

```
const [ifClicked, setIfClicked] = useState(true);
```

and a functions :

```
const handleIfClicked = () => {setIfClicked(!ifClicked)};

const extendTreatments = () =>{
dropdownFB ? setDropdownFB(false) : setDropdownFB(true);
  handleIfClicked();
}
```

I've got li element with event listeners and function above:

```
<li className="nav-item" 
    onMouseEnter={onMouseEnterFB}
    onMouseLeave={onMouseLeaveFB}
    onClick={extendTreatments}
```

I've tried to enable/disable event listeners by manipulating hook "ifClicked".
The main goal is to once element got clicked don't use event listener  "onMouseLeave" (turn it off).

```
<li className="nav-item" 
    onMouseEnter={onMouseEnterFB}
    ifClicked && onMouseLeave={onMouseLeaveFB}
    onClick={extendTreatments}
    >
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of adding/removing event listener, consider not running your function at all, if "ifClicked" is false.

```
<li className="nav-item" 
  onMouseEnter={onMouseEnterFB}
  onMouseLeave={ifClicked && onMouseLeaveFB}
  onClick={extendTreatments}
>
```